# Disable left swipe on cardview

Tags: java, android

I am using [SwipeableRecyclerView](https://github.com/brnunes/SwipeableRecyclerView) and I was wondering how I can disable left swipe?

This is my code:

**MainActivity.class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.github.brnunes.swipeablerecyclerview.SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private CardViewAdapter mAdapter;

    private ArrayList<String> mItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mItems = new ArrayList<>(30);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            mItems.add(String.format("Card number %02d", i));
        }

        OnItemTouchListener itemTouchListener = new OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCardViewTap(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tapped " + mItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onButton1Click(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Button1 in " + mItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onButton2Click(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked Button2 in " + mItems.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        mAdapter = new CardViewAdapter(mItems, itemTouchListener);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener =
                new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(recyclerView,
                        new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canSwipe(int position) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismissedBySwipeLeft(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
//                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mItems.get(position) + " swiped left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    mItems.remove(position);
                                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                }
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
//                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mItems.get(position) + " swiped right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    mItems.remove(position);
                                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                }
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(swipeTouchListener);
    }

    /**
     * Interface for the touch events in each item
     */
    public interface OnItemTouchListener {
        /**
         * Callback invoked when the user Taps one of the RecyclerView items
         *
         * @param view     the CardView touched
         * @param position the index of the item touched in the RecyclerView
         */
        public void onCardViewTap(View view, int position);

        /**
         * Callback invoked when the Button1 of an item is touched
         *
         * @param view     the Button touched
         * @param position the index of the item touched in the RecyclerView
         */
        public void onButton1Click(View view, int position);

        /**
         * Callback invoked when the Button2 of an item is touched
         *
         * @param view     the Button touched
         * @param position the index of the item touched in the RecyclerView
         */
        public void onButton2Click(View view, int position);
    }

    /**
     * A simple adapter that loads a CardView layout with one TextView and two Buttons, and
     * listens to clicks on the Buttons or on the CardView
     */
    public class CardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private List<String> cards;
        private OnItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener;

        public CardViewAdapter(List<String> cards, OnItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener) {
            this.cards = cards;
            this.onItemTouchListener = onItemTouchListener;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            viewHolder.title.setText(cards.get(i));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return cards == null ? 0 : cards.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView title;
            private Button button1;
            private Button button2;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_title);
                button1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_button1);
                button2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_button2);

                button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onItemTouchListener.onButton1Click(v, getPosition());
                    }
                });

                button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onItemTouchListener.onButton2Click(v, getPosition());
                    }
                });

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onItemTouchListener.onCardViewTap(v, getPosition());
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.class**

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.VelocityTracker;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A {@link View.OnTouchListener} that makes the list items in a {@link android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView}
 * dismissable by swiping.
 * <p/>
 * <p>Example usage:</p>
 * <p/>
 * <pre>
 * SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener touchListener =
 *         new SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener(
 *                 listView,
 *                 new SwipeDismissRecyclerViewTouchListener.OnDismissCallback() {
 *                     public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
 *                         for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
 *                             adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
 *                         }
 *                         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 *                     }
 *                 });
 * listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
 * listView.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
 * </pre>
 * <p/>
 * <p>This class Requires API level 12 or later due to use of {@link
 * android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator}.</p>
 */
public class SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    // Cached ViewConfiguration and system-wide constant values
    private int mSlop;
    private int mMinFlingVelocity;
    private int mMaxFlingVelocity;
    private long mAnimationTime;

    // Fixed properties
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private SwipeListener mSwipeListener;
    private int mViewWidth = 1; // 1 and not 0 to prevent dividing by zero

    // Transient properties
    private List<PendingDismissData> mPendingDismisses = new ArrayList<>();
    private int mDismissAnimationRefCount = 0;
    private float mAlpha;
    private float mDownX;
    private float mDownY;
    private boolean mSwiping;
    private int mSwipingSlop;
    private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
    private int mDownPosition;
    private int mAnimatingPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
    private View mDownView;
    private boolean mPaused;
    private float mFinalDelta;

    /**
     * Constructs a new swipe touch listener for the given {@link android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView}
     *
     * @param recyclerView The recycler view whose items should be dismissable by swiping.
     * @param listener     The listener for the swipe events.
     */
    public SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(RecyclerView recyclerView, SwipeListener listener) {
        ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(recyclerView.getContext());
        mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
        mMinFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity() * 16;
        mMaxFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
        mAnimationTime = recyclerView.getContext().getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mSwipeListener = listener;


        /**
         * This will ensure that this SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener is paused during list view scrolling.
         * If a scroll listener is already assigned, the caller should still pass scroll changes through
         * to this listener.
         */
        mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                setEnabled(newState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Enables or disables (pauses or resumes) watching for swipe-to-dismiss gestures.
     *
     * @param enabled Whether or not to watch for gestures.
     */
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        mPaused = !enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return handleTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        handleTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    private boolean handleTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (mViewWidth < 2) {
            mViewWidth = mRecyclerView.getWidth();
        }

        switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                if (mPaused) {
                    break;
                }

                // Find the child view that was touched (perform a hit test)
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                int childCount = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
                int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
                mRecyclerView.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
                int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
                int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
                View child;
                for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                    child = mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                    child.getHitRect(rect);
                    if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                        mDownView = child;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (mDownView != null && mAnimatingPosition != mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(mDownView)) {
                    mAlpha = mDownView.getAlpha();
                    mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                    mDownY = motionEvent.getRawY();
                    mDownPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(mDownView);
                    if (mSwipeListener.canSwipe(mDownPosition)) {
                        mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                        mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                    } else {
                        mDownView = null;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    break;
                }

                if (mDownView != null && mSwiping) {
                    // cancel
                    mDownView.animate()
                            .translationX(0)
                            .alpha(mAlpha)
                            .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                            .setListener(null);
                }
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                mVelocityTracker = null;
                mDownX = 0;
                mDownY = 0;
                mDownView = null;
                mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
                mSwiping = false;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                    break;
                }

                mFinalDelta = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
                float velocityX = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity();
                float absVelocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
                float absVelocityY = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
                boolean dismiss = false;
                boolean dismissRight = false;
                if (Math.abs(mFinalDelta) > mViewWidth / 2 && mSwiping) {
                    dismiss = true;
                    dismissRight = mFinalDelta > 0;
                } else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= absVelocityX && absVelocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity
                        && absVelocityY < absVelocityX && mSwiping) {
                    // dismiss only if flinging in the same direction as dragging
                    dismiss = (velocityX < 0) == (mFinalDelta < 0);
                    dismissRight = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
                }
                if (dismiss && mDownPosition != mAnimatingPosition && mDownPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    // dismiss
                    final View downView = mDownView; // mDownView gets null'd before animation ends
                    final int downPosition = mDownPosition;
                    ++mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                    mAnimatingPosition = mDownPosition;
                    mDownView.animate()
                            .translationX(dismissRight ? mViewWidth : -mViewWidth)
                            .alpha(0)
                            .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    performDismiss(downView, downPosition);
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    // cancel
                    mDownView.animate()
                            .translationX(0)
                            .alpha(mAlpha)
                            .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                            .setListener(null);
                }
                mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                mVelocityTracker = null;
                mDownX = 0;
                mDownY = 0;
                mDownView = null;
                mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
                mSwiping = false;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (mVelocityTracker == null || mPaused) {
                    break;
                }

                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                float deltaY = motionEvent.getRawY() - mDownY;
                if (!mSwiping && Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop && Math.abs(deltaY) < Math.abs(deltaX) / 2) {
                    mSwiping = true;
                    mSwipingSlop = (deltaX > 0 ? mSlop : -mSlop);
                }

                if (mSwiping) {
                    mDownView.setTranslationX(deltaX - mSwipingSlop);
                    mDownView.setAlpha(Math.max(0f, Math.min(mAlpha,
                            mAlpha * (1f - Math.abs(deltaX) / mViewWidth))));
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void performDismiss(final View dismissView, final int dismissPosition) {
        // Animate the dismissed list item to zero-height and fire the dismiss callback when
        // all dismissed list item animations have completed. This triggers layout on each animation
        // frame; in the future we may want to do something smarter and more performant.

        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = dismissView.getLayoutParams();
        final int originalLayoutParamsHeight = lp.height;
        final int originalHeight = dismissView.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);

        animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                --mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                if (mDismissAnimationRefCount == 0) {
                    // No active animations, process all pending dismisses.
                    // Sort by descending position
                    Collections.sort(mPendingDismisses);

                    int[] dismissPositions = new int[mPendingDismisses.size()];
                    for (int i = mPendingDismisses.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        dismissPositions[i] = mPendingDismisses.get(i).position;
                    }

                    if (mFinalDelta > 0) {
                        mSwipeListener.onDismissedBySwipeRight(mRecyclerView, dismissPositions);
                    } else {
                        mSwipeListener.onDismissedBySwipeLeft(mRecyclerView, dismissPositions);
                    }

                    // Reset mDownPosition to avoid MotionEvent.ACTION_UP trying to start a dismiss
                    // animation with a stale position
                    mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
                    for (PendingDismissData pendingDismiss : mPendingDismisses) {
                        // Reset view presentation
                        pendingDismiss.view.setAlpha(mAlpha);
                        pendingDismiss.view.setTranslationX(0);

                        lp = pendingDismiss.view.getLayoutParams();
                        lp.height = originalLayoutParamsHeight;

                        pendingDismiss.view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    }

                    // Send a cancel event
                    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(time, time,
                            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, 0, 0, 0);
                    mRecyclerView.dispatchTouchEvent(cancelEvent);

                    mPendingDismisses.clear();
                    mAnimatingPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
                }
            }
        });

        animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                lp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                dismissView.setLayoutParams(lp);
            }
        });

        mPendingDismisses.add(new PendingDismissData(dismissPosition, dismissView));
        animator.start();
    }

    /**
     * The callback interface used by {@link SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener} to inform its client
     * about a swipe of one or more list item positions.
     */
    public interface SwipeListener {
        /**
         * Called to determine whether the given position can be swiped.
         */
        boolean canSwipe(int position);

        /**
         * Called when the item has been dismissed by swiping to the left.
         *
         * @param recyclerView           The originating {@link android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView}.
         * @param reverseSortedPositions An array of positions to dismiss, sorted in descending
         *                               order for convenience.
         */
        void onDismissedBySwipeLeft(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);

        /**
         * Called when the item has been dismissed by swiping to the right.
         *
         * @param recyclerView           The originating {@link android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView}.
         * @param reverseSortedPositions An array of positions to dismiss, sorted in descending
         *                               order for convenience.
         */
        void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);
    }

    class PendingDismissData implements Comparable<PendingDismissData> {
        public int position;
        public View view;

        public PendingDismissData(int position, View view) {
            this.position = position;
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(@NonNull PendingDismissData other) {
            // Sort by descending position
            return other.position - position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find out the answer ? I am also having the same issue!!!

Comment: Nope not yet.Let me know if you do? Thanks

Comment: CHeck out my answer it is late but it is much better solution . Very easy and there is no need of doing much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple recyclerView and then You can use **ItemTouchHelper.Callback**

```
public class SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

private final YourAdapter mAdapter;

public SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(YourAdapter adapter) {
    mAdapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
    return true;
}


@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
    int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                      RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    mAdapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}

}
```

In **YourAdapter** class which is extending recyclerview adapter add these functions.

```
public void onItemMove(int oldPosition, int newPosition) {
    notifyItemMoved(oldPosition,newPosition);

}

 public void onItemDismiss(int adapterPosition) {
  /// here you can delete from the array and notify for that specific position
 }
```

**ItemTouchHelper** provides some flags which you can see here

```
 @Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
    int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
}
```

If you want to disable *Left to Right Swipe* just remove **ItemTouchHelper.START** flag.

If you want to disable *Right to Left Swipe* just remove **ItemTouchHelper.END** flag.

You can pass **0** value instead of **swipeFlags**. Swipe will not work.

Same goes for **dragFlags**.

I have implemented this as well and it works like a charm ;) Happy Coding <3